# Creating a global modal using react-redux and foundation reveal

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm creating a modal that displays information about a specific user and it's triggered by clicking on a picture. The modal should be able to fire up from different components. My approach is as follows (I use React with Redux):

1. create store with a "modal" property that's set to a reducer "modalReducer"

   ```
   modal: modalReducer
   ```
2. modal is an object with the following properties: showModal=false, user=undefined, image=undefined
3. When a div containing picture is clicked, the action is being dispatched that sets showModal to true (with username and url image link as arguments).

`export var openModal = (user, image) => {
      return {
        type: 'OPEN_MODAL',
        user,
        image
      }
    }`

4. For the actual modal I use a [foundation reveal modal](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html) and in its render method I check if **modal.showModal == true** and use jQuery to open it up.

Now, toggling the modal works as charm but I cannot use the modal.user and modal.image properties inside of the render method as it prints the following error message:

> Uncaught Error: findComponentRoot(..., .0.2.0.0.1): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a  when using tables, nesting tags like ,
>
> , or , or using non-SVG elements in an  parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``.

I'm almost certain the problem lies within the ProfileModal.jsx component. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
export class ProfileModal extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    var elem = new Foundation.Reveal($('#profile-modal'));
    $('#profile-modal').on('closed.zf.reveal',()=>{this.props.dispatch(actions.hideModal())});
  }
  render () {
    var {modal} = this.props;
    if (modal.showModal) {
      $('#profile-modal').foundation('open');
    }
      return(
        <div>
          <div id="profile-modal" className="reveal large">
            <div className="modal-container">
              <div className="modal-picture" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${modal.image})`}}></div>
              <p>{modal.user}</p>
...
```

Comment: I think the Foundation Reveal JS code is messing with the root element of the react component. Modals often work by moving the element somewhere to the root of body. React wants to rerender when you change the props, but it can no longer find back the element that it first created in the DOM.

Comment: I see, looks like I won't be using foundation reveal for my project. Do you have any suggestions as to what modal to use or should I write my own?

Comment: there are a lot of packages out there! https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal seems to be popular, check http://madscript.com/boron/, or ui kits like Elemental, React-Bootstrap that have a modal component. There are also a few already hooked up to redux.

Comment: I did manage to get my own idea working, the main problem was that the Foundation Reveal was hiding the modal in css, not actually removing it from the DOM. I managed to fix that by making it a child of another component and passing state as prop whether to render it or not. Thanks for the head-up, I'll be trying out these modals in future!